# Autonomous equation having $\frac{t^2}{1+t}$ as a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find an autonomous equation having $\displaystyle\frac{t^2}{1+t}$ as a solution.

So the desired function $f$ should depend only on $x$, if I'm not wrong in the form $x'=f(x)$, that means the goal is to write $t$ as a function of $x$, but this seems almost impossible, however I compute the derivative;

$$\bigg(\frac{t^2}{1+t}\bigg)'=\frac{2t}{(1+t)}-\frac{t^2}{(1+t)^2}$$

and $$x=\frac{t^2}{1+t}=t-\frac{t}{(1+t)}$$

for example, if I try $\displaystyle -x^2=-\frac{t^2}{(1+t)^2}-t^2+\frac{2t}{(1+t)}$

the middle part is redundant, how can I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: solve $x = t^2/(1+t)$ for $t$ in terms of $x$. Differentiate the resulting equation $t = T(x(t))$ with respect to $t$, and isolate $x'(t)$.

Comment: That's the problem I cannot write $t$ only in terms of $x$, there are also $x'$

Comment: $(1+t)x = t^2$ is a quadratic equation in $t$.  You can solve that.

Comment: OK, thanks. why can I not just substitute $t=\frac{-x\pm\sqrt{x^2-4x}}{2}$ in the derivative ?

Comment: You can do it that way too.  By the way, you might think about whether you want to use the $+$ or the $-$.  You're usually more interested in $t > 0$ than $t < 0$.

Comment: I think first computation was wrong, if I do it correctly $t=\frac{x\pm\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{2}$, to make $t$ positive, it is better to use $+$, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

How about $\frac{d^3}{dt^3}(x'+x^2)=0$

Comment: you mean $\frac12\frac{d}{dt}(x'+x^2)=t$, then I just substitute the derivative with $\frac{(x'+x^2)'(1+(x'+x^2)')-(\frac12(x'+x^2)')^2}{(1+\frac12(x'+x^2)')^2}$ ?

Comment: $x''+2xx'=2t$, then $x'''+2x'^2+2xx''=2$ is autonomous.

Comment: But if $x = t^2/(1+t)$, $x'' + 2 x x'$ is not $t$.

Comment: However, you do have $x^2 + 4 x + x' = t^2 + 2 t$.

Comment: ... so that $(x^2 + 4 x + x')'' = 2$.

Comment: Ah, the third term in implicit's equation for $-x^2$ should have $2t^2$ in the numerator.